# Trouble linking libraries in FFTW

Tags: makefile, mpi

This error happens when I try to execute a Makefile:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrfftw_mpi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw_mpi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrfftw
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The corresponding .so libraries are placed in /usr/lib:

```
librfftw_mpi.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/librfftw_mpi.so.2
librfftw.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/librfftw.so.2

libfftw_mpi.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libfftw_mpi.so.2
```

I tried to create symbolic links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libfftw.so.2 /usr/bin/libfftw.so
```

but it didn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Suggestion: Edit your question and include the content of Makefile, which might help other users to figure out what didn't work.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I asked the question offline and now my problem has been solved. First I have to edit the Makefile so that the library is linked to the actual path on my computer:

Answer (score 0):

Actually my problem has been solved (I asked the question offline):

- For this particular code, double precision FFTW must be used, so I edited back this Makefile line to return it into its original state:

  ```
  FFTW_LIB =  $(FFTW_LIBS) -ldrfftw_mpi -ldfftw_mpi -ldrfftw -ldfftw
  ```

Single-precision FFTW *does* generate a Makefile, but it won't work.

- Edit the FFTW_LIBS line so that the correct path to my computer (`/home/van/fftw/lib/`) is linked:

  ```
  FTW_LIBS=  -L/home/van/fftw/lib/
  ```
- Add this line to the `~/.bashrc` file so that the executable is always linked to all its dependencies:

  ```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/van/fftw/lib
  ```