# Why won't Ubuntu let me install fftw-2.1.5 -- I get the error "214: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed"

Tags: command-line, make

When I try and run the `make install` command in ubuntu's terminal, I get the below error. I cannot install any later versions because I am running an old code called GADGET2.

```
Making install in fftw
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/webb/Documents/fftw-2.1.5/fftw'
    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/webb/Documents/fftw-2.1.5/fftw'
    /bin/bash ../mkinstalldirs /usr/local/lib
     /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c  libfftw.la /usr/local/lib/libfftw.la
    /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libfftw.lai /usr/local/lib/libfftw.la
    /usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libfftw.la': Permission denied
    Makefile:297: recipe for target 'install-libLTLIBRARIES' failed
    make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/webb/Documents/fftw-2.1.5/fftw'
    Makefile:568: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
    make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/webb/Documents/fftw-2.1.5/fftw'
    Makefile:214: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
    make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I now get the error

```
PEPREFIX_FFTW         -I/usr/common/pdsoft/include -I/usr/local/include    -c -o longrange.o longrange.c
mpicc    main.o  run.o  predict.o begrun.o endrun.o global.o timestep.o  init.o restart.o  io.o accel.o   read_ic.o  ngb.o system.o  allocate.o  density.o gravtree.o hydra.o  driftfac.o domain.o  allvars.o potential.o forcetree.o   peano.o gravtree_forcetest.o pm_periodic.o pm_nonperiodic.o longrange.o   -g    -L/usr/common/pdsoft/lib  -Wl,"-R /usr/common/pdsoft/lib" -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -L/usr/local/lib -lrfftw_mpi -lfftw_mpi -lrfftw -lfftw    -o  Gadget2  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrfftw_mpi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw_mpi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:242: recipe for target 'Gadget2' failed
make: *** [Gadget2] Error 1
```

after fixing the first error

Comment: `/usr/local/lib` doesn't allow regular users to create/modify contents inside. Have you tried `sudo make install` instead of `make install`?

Comment: Cheers, I tried that and now get a different erro. It runs past the point you helped me with but gets stuck at the new error I added above

Comment: See if [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/710372/816190) helps.

Comment: I would recommend to simply install [`fftw-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=fftw-dev) and then compile your application.